# Simple-Schema: fields without types

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

Is there a way of declaring a field of any type? 
Nothing seems to be documented, so I tried

```
foo: {
  type: undefined
  blackbox: yes
}
```

My issue:

When I run an `update` on the collection, it works for scalar values. But if `foo` is an array, what gets saved is an array of nulls.
I narrowed the issue down to the simple-schema declaration of `foo`. As a *temporary work-around*, I've disabled the use of this schema branch for now (blackbox-ed the parent of `foo`).

Is there a more proper way of declaring the schema for field `foo`?

Comment: I've just found 
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/174  

It seems unsolvable with the current state of simple-schema

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not currently possible:

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/174

Comment: thanks for answering @tarmes, although it doesn't help: I've already posted this non-solution as a comment above. I'm leaving the question open, hopefully the current state will change and someone will post an update

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the blackbox option:

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#blackbox

Comment: @BogdanD Ok, undefined isn't a valid type.  Try "object" and use a subproperty.